# What is the Lagrangian for the interaction of graviphoton with matter?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gravity, photons, field-theory, supersymmetry

There are some models that postulate the existence of graviphoton. What is the Lagrangian for the interaction of graviphoton with matter?

Comment: Well, there are two [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviphoton): the K-K one and the N>1, so extended, supergravity one. They all involve a charge proportional to m/M(Planck). The refs in WP have typical toy Lagrangians...